# How to use a browser on a remote server for an automated tests

Tags: javascript, jquery, linux, iframe, jenkins

I inherited a project where the person wrote tools to test our site's UI using JQuery and JS.

I don't know too much about it other than it requires a browser to be spawned and I think the tool uses JS to interact with iframes to see if it's the expected values.

My job is to get this tool to run on a remote server and post the results to Jenkins.

The remote test server and staging server is linux.  From our staging server, I want to write a script to spawn a browser and run cmds from the tool to test our UI.  I ran the following manually:

```
ssh -X user@remote_test_server /usr/bin/firefox
```

However, the remote server says:

```
Error: no display specified
```

Is there a way to spawn a browser for automated testing from one headless server to another?  Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar problem when I tried to automate a GUI installation program. While there are quite some different possibilities to choose from (e.g. Xnest, Xephyr?), I ended up using vncserver, because it's relatively easy to debug the GUI session this way.

You need to create a vncpassword file, I think:

```
mkdir -p $HOME/.vnc
chmod 0700 $HOME/.vnc
echo MyLittlePassword | vncpasswd -f > $HOME/.vnc/passwd
chmod 0600 $HOME/.vnc/passwd
```

Starting the server is then quite straightforward

```
vncserver
export DISPLAY=:1
/usr/bin/firefox&
...
```

Now it is possible to connect to the VNC server with a VNC viewer of your choice. But beware there may be no window manager, depending on the X startup scripts of your environment.

Shutting the server down

```
vncserver -kill :1
```

Answer (score 1):

In the configuration of Jenkins project , specify the 
**Build Environment**

- Start Xvfb before the build, and shut it down after.

[image]

#

[image]